# Importing a namespace vs. including files in PHP

Tags: php, namespaces

I have started building my code library since PHP 4. I have used `require_once` to import classes. Now with PHP 5.3 I have met defining namespaces and importing them.

I would like to change my source files to use importing (`use` statement) instead of using `require_once`. Is this the right decision, I am not sure.

I guess it would be easy. Defining namespace at the top of class files and doing a search & replace on other files that use them (replace `require_once` with `use`). On practice what may go wrong?

And will there be performance improvement? On including file it is obvious how PHP finds the file. But on importing namespaces it is not that obvious. Is there a performance loss on searching namespaces and indexing them by PHP?

Comment: namespaces are a way to avoid collision between classes having same name, while require loads the class. It's better to use autoloading feature than using require multiple times.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`use` and `require_once` are completely different things. `use` is not doing any file importing at all. `use` is just making your life easier. Instead of writing `Full\Path\To\Class` every time, you can do

```
use Full\Path\To\Class

$bar = new Class();
```

Your are still responsible to include the right files.

Instead of loading all the files by hand, you could rely on [PHP auto class loading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php).

You can use [Composer](http://getcomposer.org/) or Frameworks like [Symfony 2](http://symfony.com/) or [Zend2](http://framework.zend.com/) which are handling all the autoloading stuff for you.

Migrating existing code to use autoloading and `use` statements instead of `include_once` may be very time consuming. There's most likely no search and replace solution.

Comment: thanks, I did not notice auto class loading. However it sounds like a bad practice, which can only be implemented in an interpreter language. It adds overhead like searching whole path for a class and leads to bad documentation that you don't know which file uses what.

Comment: I did never see any performance problems because auf auto class loading. If you use the mentioned tools you can see that they do a lot to make sure the look-up is fast. After all Java is doing this successfuly for more than a decade. And last but not least: Relying on simple rules for include/class loading simplifys your code considerably.

Comment: @bkilinc : Standards like PSR-0 allow you to use consistent rules for autoloading throughout your application. If your entire library applies that same standard, you can use a single autoloader for your your entire application. That allows you to write very modular OOP code without worrying about dependencies, while reducing performance overhead to an absolute minimum.

Comment: @JohnSlegers : thanks, It has been sometime since asking the question. Right now my class library is fully refactored, using namespaces and class overloading extensively. I use single autoloader and a lookup table for legacy code. I would prefer declaring imports (require's) in code, but my IDE is not powerful to manage them, besides I prefer to stick to Zend Framework standards.

Comment: @bkilinc : Personally, I use a lightweight zero config autoloader that I created myself. It automatically loads any library that's compatible with the PSR-0 standard (https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md ) from one or more configurable paths. It doesn't require composer either.